# React Native how get data from asynchrone function

Tags: react-native, async-await

I try to get data from an asynchronestorage function

```
 _retrieveData = async () => {
        var test = await AsyncStorage.getItem('myitem')
        return test
 }

 _generateRandomCards() {
        console.log(this._retrieveData())
 }
```

But that return :

```
Promise {
  "_U": 0,
  "_V": 0,
  "_W": null,
  "_X": null,
}
```

Edit : After the answer of Václav Ryska, i can change it with setstate, but that reload once if i call getValue from componentDidMount, and infinite loop in my generaterandomcards function.

My code :

```
 componentDidMount() {
        this.getValue()
    }

    getValue = async () => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('key')
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({deckDrawToday: true});
        })
    }

_generateRandomCards() {
  console.log(this.state.deckDrawToday)
  ...
  this._generateRandomCardsTrue()
  ...
  return (
            this._generateViewCards()
        )
}

_generateRandomCardsTrue() {
 ...
}

_generateViewCards() {
 ...
}

render() {
        return (
            this._generateRandomCards()
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

return is not a valid statement for async functions, you gotta set the value in a callback to a variable

```
this.state = {
    value: null
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getValue();
}

getValue = async () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('key')
    .then(data => {
        this.setState({value: data});
        console.log(data)
    })
}
```

Comment: i have try like this, but that reload my functions once, on i can do for not reload again ?

Comment: depends on where you call `this.getValue()` function, if you put it in `componentDidMount()` then it gets called only after first render, you can put it inside a button like `<Button onPress={() => this.getValue()}>`

Comment: i have edit my first post for explain with my code

Answer (score 0):

use `console.log(await this._retrieveData())` since your function is async

Comment: If i add 'async' to my function i have this error : Objects are not valid as React Child

Comment: use .then()     instead of await